# Why can not Myelin sheath be fully rebuilt?

Tags: ophthalmology, omega-3, optic-nerve, anti-inflammatory, myelin-sheath

I've joined a group on Facebook. It's about people that have optic neuritis. After recovery, The affected eye is back to its original state. There's always a very very small deficiency in the eyesight. There's always a difference between the healthy eye and the affected eye. It never becomes like what god have created.
People in the group told me that and I myself experienced it.

Even if doctors said that my sight is 20/20. Patients feels like It might be 19.98/20 :D

I'm not an eye doctor but I've gathered some info. about optic neuritis and how myelin sheath is partially destroyed. But I still don't know why myelin sheath can not be recovered 100% so that eyesight become 100% too.

I think the following protocol is good enough to rebuild all damaged parts of myelin sheath:

1. Solu-medrol is anti-inflammation injections.
2. Some other medicines reduces immune system function.
3. Taking vitamin and omega-3 pills.

The only reason that I can guess is that the rate or regeneration of myelin is lower (less) than the rate of damaging by immune system. It's like pouring water into a drilled bottle (a bottle that has a hole). The bottle will never run out of water. But at the same time, It will never be full of water. Am I right?

Thank you very much,